# powershell: Outlook mailbox up to date?

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-automation

I have a Powershell script that automates some Outlook tasks. I would like to only run certain tasks when the Outlook client mailbox is fully synced and up to date. When I open Outlook, the inbox is out of date and I dont want to manipulate the inbox until it is up to date.

Is there a way to interrogate the Outlook client object to find out if all the mailboxes are up to date?

```
# get outlook inbox
$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application;
$ns = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI");
$inbox = $ns.Folders.Item("me@example.com").Folders.Item("Inbox")

# wait for mailbox to sync
while ($inbox.notUpToDate) {
   sleep;
}

# then manipulate msgs in $inbox
```

Comment: You can use `Get-MsolCompanyInformation` to see last DirSync time that might be of use to you

Comment: What version of PowerShell (`$PSVersionTable` will give you this) are you working with?

Comment: @Deckerz I will check it out. Is it not possible to query the Outlook object?@gravity `PS Version 2.0`

Comment: @Deckerz I am accessing the Outlook object (using the MAPI namesapce) already to automate tasks in Outlook. That is the basis for my entire script. I am just wondering is its possible get the sync status. I don't see it in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869848.aspx).

Comment: @Deckerz I cannot use Get-MsolCompanyInformation in my powershell script. I'm not accessing Microsoft Online. I am trying to query my Outlook application to see is it is synced up with the Exchange server.

Comment: @gravity version: 5.1.14393.1770

Comment: You are trying to validate if your local `Outlook` client has synced?  I think, originally, it was thought you were trying to validate, through the parent Exchange server, if your client had recently updated.  Two different solutions, for two different issues.

Comment: I have updated the original post to clarify the situation. @gravity Can you clarify what you think the solution is? I cannot use Get-MsolCompanyInformation in my scenario. I dont see two solutions.